# How can I retrieve Amazon's keyword/phrase suggestions from the search bar

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

Below is some code I've found and altered to attempt to capture the keyword/phrase suggestions from Amazon's search bar. I'm very new to the concept of web scraping, so I know the code presented here may be very ineffective and inefficient. I've manually captured some data from the F12 DOM Explorer and Network windows. If the best answer is web scraping, I need that in the form of excel vba. I see in some of the below images that it appears as though some of the content type from the Network window is "application/json" and the Initiator/Type is "XMLHttpRequest", but this is only after it shows a connection and authentication to "https://completion.amazon.com". If that's the route, I have no idea how to complete those requests. Any help would be much appreciated.

So far I've tried invoking the search bar programmatically, via the scripts in the code, but that does nothing that I can see. Simply 'pasting' the keyword into the search bar with a 'space' appended to it does not produce the suggested keywords. However, typing into the search bar does. If I type the keyword in, then choose 'inspect element' of the dropdown suggestions, dynamic HTML is produced to show the HTML content of the suggestions (at which time I can get what I need). I've been unsuccessful in getting to that point.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String

Dim AASearchRank As Workbook
Dim AAws As Worksheet
Dim InputSearch As HTMLInputTextElement
Dim elems As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim elems2 As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement2 As HTMLDivElement
'Dim TDelement2 As HTMLInputTextElement

Dim InputSearchButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Long

MyURL = "https://www.amazon.com/"
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate MyURL
    .Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End With
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set AASearchRank = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set AAws = AASearchRank.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set InputSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("nav-search-submit-text")
Set InputSearchOrder = HTMLDoc.getElementById("twotabsearchtextbox")

If Not InputSearchOrder Is Nothing Then
    InputSearchButton.Click
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End If

x = 2
If AAws.Range("D" & x).Value = "" Then
    Do Until AAws.Range("B" & x) = ""
        Set InputSearch = HTMLDoc.getElementById("twotabsearchtextbox")
        InputSearch.Focus
        'When a keyword is typed in the search bar with a 'space' after, it invokes the suggestions I'm looking for.
        InputSearch.Value = "Travel "
        'InputSearch.Value = AAws.Range("C" & x) & " "

        Set InputSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("nav-input")(0)
        InputSearch.Focus

        'Here I was trying to invoke some script to see if it had any effect on the search bar drop down
        HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.navmet.push({key:'UpNav',end:+new Date(),begin:window.navmet.tmp});"
        HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.navmet.push({key:'Search',end:+new Date(),begin:window.navmet.tmp});"
        HTMLDoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.navmet.push({key:'NavBar',end:+new Date(),begin:window.navmet.main});"

            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))


        Set elems2 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("nav-issFlyout nav-flyout")
        i = 0
        For Each TDelement2 In elems2
                'Debug statements strictly for learning what each option/query returns
                Debug.Print TDelement2.innerText
                Debug.Print TDelement2.className
                Debug.Print TDelement2.dataFld

                Debug.Print TDelement2.innerHTML
                Debug.Print TDelement2.outerText
                Debug.Print TDelement2.outerHTML
                Debug.Print TDelement2.parentElement.className
                Debug.Print TDelement2.tagName
                Debug.Print TDelement2.ID

        Next

        'Once the searchbar is populated, and the drop down list provides suggestions,
        'the below code will give me what I want. If there's an easier solution,
        'I'm all for it
        Set elems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("s-suggestion")
        i = 0
        For Each TDelement In elems
            If Left(TDelement.ID, 6) = "issDiv" Then
                Debug.Print TDelement.innerText
                Debug.Print TDelement.ID
            End If

        Next
    x = x + 1
    Loop
End If
```

End Sub

An ideal solution would be to obtain these suggested keywords through either invoking the search bar dynamic HTML or via Amazon's completion site, but it appears as though that might not be open to the general public. Thank you for any help, and apologies up front for any posting deficiencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API call you can find in the network tab. It returns a json string you can parse with as [jsonparser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to get the suggestions. I use jsonconverter.bas which, once downloaded I add to the project and then go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

The url itself is a queryString i.e. it is constructed of different parameters. For example, there is a `limit` parameter, whose value is `11`, which specifies the number of suggestions to return. You may be able to alter and/or remove some of these. Below, I concatenate the `SEARCH_TERM` constant into the query string to represent your search value (that which would be typed into the search box).

I don't know whether any of the params are time-based (i.e. expire over time - I have made a number of requests without problem since you posted your question). It may be that necessary time based values can be pulled via a prior GET request to Amazon search page.

```
params = (
    ('session-id', '141-0042012-2829544'),
    ('customer-id', ''),
    ('request-id', '7E7YCB7AZZM1HQEZF2G1'),
    ('page-type', 'Search'),
    ('lop', 'en_US'),
    ('site-variant', 'desktop'),
    ('client-info', 'amazon-search-ui'),
    ('mid', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'),
    ('alias', 'aps'),
    ('b2b', '0'),
    ('fresh', '0'),
    ('ks', '76'),
    ('prefix', 'TRAVEL'),
    ('event', 'onKeyPress'),
    ('limit', '11'),
    ('fb', '1'),
    ('suggestion-type', ['KEYWORD', 'WIDGET']),
    ('_', '1556820864750')
)
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim json As Object, suggestion As Object                '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Const SEARCH_TERM As String = "TRAVEL"
    Const SEARCH_TERM2 As String = "BOOKS"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://completion.amazon.com/api/2017/suggestions?session-id=141-0042012-2829544" & _
        "&customer-id=&request-id=7E7YCB7AZZM1HQEZF2G1&page-type=Search&lop=en_US&site-variant=" & _
        "desktop&client-info=amazon-search-ui&mid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&alias=aps&b2b=0&fresh=0&ks=76&" & _
        "prefix=" & SEARCH_TERM & "&event=onKeyPress&limit=11&fb=1&suggestion-type=KEYWORD&suggestion-type=" & _
        "WIDGET&_=1556820864750", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("suggestions")
    End With
    For Each suggestion In json
        Debug.Print suggestion("value")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr - thank you so much for the quick response. When I try to execute your code, I get a 'Sub or Function not defined' for the 'WriteTxtFile .responseText' line.

Comment: My apologies - I forgot to include the 'Option Explicit' statement....now that I've done that, I'm getting a 'Variable not defined' for 'JsonConverter'.

Comment: Have you installed the jsonconverter.bas into your project from the link?

Comment: Any problems  let me know

Comment: I have not installed that yet - didn't understand that was a part of the solution. Is there not a way to do this without installing jsonconverter.bas? How might it be "installed into my project"? Thank you for your patience...

Comment: create a new module in your project and rename it JsonConverter (press F4 to rename). Copy code from [link](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) into that module.

Comment: Ok - installed the code into a module and renamed as you suggested. I still get the 'Sub or Function not defined' for the 'WriteTxtFile'.

Comment: delete that line. It is not in my current answer above. It is a debug function of mine.

Comment: Awesome Qharr...I've been battling this for 3 weeks! Thankful for your very quick response time, and the quick execution of the code! Much, much appreciated!!!!

Comment: My apologies - I tried to give you credit for your answer, but it wouldn't let me!

Comment: QHarr (or anyone else): back to your statement "It may be that necessary time based values can be pulled via a prior GET request to Amazon search page". I've been running this frequently since the last post and I'm starting to see changes in the results returned; i.e. outdated. How can your statement be implemented to always request the latest and greatest? Thanks in advance!